# React dynamically create buttons that open the corresponding modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, modal-dialog

I am trying to dynamically display 3 buttons that each open a different modal. I'm struggling with finding the solution to open the modal that belongs to the button.
I tried to implement it like the code below. It doesn't work which I expected but I"m struggling with finding the correct way of achieving the desired result.

button - modal code:

```
export default function SidenavButtons(props) {
    const [modalShow, setModalShow] = React.useState(false);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>

            <a class="dropdown-item" onClick={() => {setModalShow(true)}}>{props.usage}</a>
            {
                if(props.usage === "post" && modalShow){
                    <CreatePostModal
                    show={modalShow}
                    onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
                    modelUsage={props.usage}
                />
                }
                if(props.usage === "tweet" && modalShow){
                    <CreateTweetModal
                    show={modalShow}
                    onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
                    modelUsage={props.usage}
                />
                }
                if(props.usage === "tiktok" && modalShow){
                    <CreateTiktokModal
                    show={modalShow}
                    onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
                    modelUsage={props.usage}
                />
                }
            }


        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is using the if statement inside the return. You can just use the expression itself like the following

```
export default function SidenavButtons(props) {
    const [modalShow, setModalShow] = React.useState(false);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>

            <a class="dropdown-item" onClick={() => {setModalShow(true)}}>{props.usage}</a>
                {props.usage === "post" && modalShow &&
                    <CreatePostModal
                        show={modalShow}
                        onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
                        modelUsage={props.usage}
                    />
                }
                {props.usage === "tweet" && modalShow &&
                    <CreateTweetModal
                        show={modalShow}
                        onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
                        modelUsage={props.usage}
                    />
                }
                {props.usage === "tiktok" && modalShow &&
                    <CreateTiktokModal
                        show={modalShow}
                        onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
                        modelUsage={props.usage}
                    />
                }
            }

        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't know you could do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this:

```js
export default function SidenavButton(props) {
    const [modalShow, setModalShow] = React.useState(false);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <a class="dropdown-item" onClick={() => {setModalShow(true)}}>{props.usage}</a>
            {modalShow && (
              <Modal onHide={() => setModalShow(false)} show>
                {props.usage === 'post' && (
                  // Put here the content that would go inside CreatePostModal
                )}
                {props.usage === 'tweet' && (
                  // Put here the content that would go inside CreateTweetModal
                )}
                {props.usage === 'tiktok' && (
                  // Put here the content that would go inside CreateTiktokModal
                )}
              </Modal>
            )}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

And the Modal element would look something like this:

```js
export default function Modal(props) {
  return <React.Fragment>
    {props.show && (
      <div className="modal-class-name">
        //Here I use props.children to render everything that is rendered inside 
        //the modal
        {props.children}
        <button onClick={props.onHide}>Close</button>
      </div>
    )}
  </React.Fragment>
}
```

I like this approach because it separates the concerns. There is a `Modal` component that handles showing stuff on a Modal and there is the `SidenavButton` component that uses `Modal` to render stuff in a modal depending on the usage.

Finally, just a quick reminder:

```js
if(props.usage === "tiktok" && modalShow){
    <CreateTiktokModal
      show={modalShow}
      onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
      modelUsage={props.usage}
    />
}
```

Will not render anything because you can only put values inside brackets, not actual javascript code, the correct implementation would be:

```js
{
  (props.usage === "tiktok" && modalShow) && (
    <CreateTiktokModal
      show={modalShow}
      onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
      modelUsage={props.usage}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: I like that you give a different perspective on how I could solve the problem. I'm going to remember this one for future projects! Thank you